# Xamarin.Forms App Quits immediately after launch

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hej,

ive got a weird problem that im researching for days now...
If i try to run my xamarin.forms android app on the Visual Studio android emulator, it launches and quits immediately with no Exception or Errors and no Warnings.

Im using the Latest Xamarin.Forms version, and the Android 23 API.

Im using Visual Studio Debugger.

Logcat http://pastebin.com/36TWh3u4

Comment: Can you post the logcat? How are you deploying - from Visual Studio debugger or side-loading?

Comment: im deploying with Visual studio debugger. Edit for Logcat Errors. But the App works just fine on my other PC without any bugs, the app is basicly finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem when my CPU was configured incorrectly in Hyper-v on windows 10. Try this

1. Open Hyper-V manager
2. Make sure the emulator in question is switched off
3. Find the emulator right click and choose settings
4. Go to processor
5. Expand the tree view
6. Select compatability
7. Turn on -> 'Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version'
8. Apply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i turn off Hyper v then i cant access the emulator settings. am i missing something

Comment: because im using Visual Studio emulator for android and the emulator requires hyper v to work

Comment: instructions were unclear. I've edited step 2 to make it clear that it is not hyper v that you turn off.

Comment: No worries, it was a real pain for me too, hope this helps you and anyone else who runs into this.